# How to show that Denseness of the Operator T?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider  the operator $~T:D(T)\subset H^2(\Omega)\rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$  with domain

$Dom(T):=\{u:u\in H^2(\Omega) ~\mbox{such that }~ au(x)+bu'(x)=0~ \mbox{for all}~ x\in \partial \Omega   \}$.

Then, how to show that the operator $T$ is densely defined?

**My approach:**
Let $C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$ be  the set of infinetly differentiable functions on $\Omega$ which vanishes at the boundry. We can see that
$$ C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)\subset D(T)\subset H^{2}(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega) $$ and then using that  $$\overline{C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)}^{\|\cdot\|_{L^2(\Omega)}}=L^2(\Omega).$$
Is it correct approach to get required denseness? Please help.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for you comment. But I have confusion about  boundary conditions. Will  this approach really cover  the boundary conditions ?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it some more I am not totally sure if this works because of funniness at the boundary, however what you may instead want to do is consider a modification of your guess. Consider this set $$\{f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega) : \operatorname{supp}(f) \cap \partial\Omega = \emptyset\}.$$ This would be the smooth functions that vanish on a neighborhood of $\partial\Omega$ which implies their derivatives do too which can be seen from doing difference quotients. You can show without too much difficulty that you can approximate any $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ function with these.

Comment: Thanks @CameronWilliams, yes it seems now proper space to start the procedure. Is this space same to space $C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$ i.e. space consisting smooth functions with compact support on $(\omega)$?

Comment: Almost! Those functions are only defined on $\Omega$ and assuming $\Omega$ does not contain its boundary, these functions cannot actually be evaluated on the boundary. You can however canonically identify them with functions on $\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$ by $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x)$ if $x\in \Omega$ and $\tilde{f}(x) = 0$ if $x\in\partial\Omega$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it seems to make sense now. Thanks for the answer.